# Check if you can make word2 out of the letters of word1

Tags: c++

The task is to input two words that are made up of uppercase latin letters that are >1 and <250 characters and have the program output whether the second word can be made out of the 1st word's letters.

I only pass 11/12 tests. After asking 3 people for help and using their codes, I started getting 4/12... that's why I'm here.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word1, word2; // inputted words
    cin >> word1 >> word2;
    if (word2.size() > word1.size())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < word1.size(); i++) // safe proofing
    {
        if (islower(word1[i]) || islower(word2[i]) || word1.size() < 1
                || word1.size() > 250 || word2.size() < 1 || word2.size() > 250)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    int sk1 = 0, sk2 = 0; // times a letter appears in the respective words
    int a = 0; // variable outside of for loop for the end if statement to work
    for (a; a < word2.size(); a++) //checks how many times each letter of the 2nd 
                                   //word appears in both words
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < word1.size(); i++) //checks how many times the letter 
                                               //appears in the 1st word
        {
            if (word2[a] == word1[i])
            {
                sk1++; // counts the times it appears
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < word2.size(); i++) //checks how many times the letter 
                                               //appears in the 2nd word
        {
            if (word2[a] == word2[i])
            {
                sk2++; // counts the times it appears
            }
        }
        if (sk1 < sk2) // if the 1st word has less of the letter than needed, 
                       //it outputs that you can't make the 2nd word
        {
            cout << "NO";
            break;
        }
        sk1 = 0;
        sk2 = 0;
    }
    if (a == word2.size()) //if it goes through all the letters and there are enough 
                           //of them to make the 2nd word, it says that it can be made.
    {
        cout << "YES";
    }
}
```

Comment: Recommend that you pick a failure case and provide the inputs for it, otherwise we're shooting blind out here. We might hit a bug, but not necessarily the one your're asking for.

Comment: `word1.size() < 1 || word1.size() > 250 || word2.size() < 1 || word2.size() > 250` can be move outside the loop.

Comment: for `if (word2.size() > word1.size())` you don't print `NO`.

Comment: Note also there are `char` which are neither lower or upper case (punctuation for example).

Comment: @MrE.: Check the answer

Comment: ASCII is only 127 characters. The Latin alphabet is in range `65 - 91` Capital letters and  from `97 - 122` for the Small letters. the remaining interval contains whitespaces, other characters. So you can make your loop loops only over the capita and using `ispper()` and `islower`.

Answer (score 2):

1. First the you take a array `a[26]` or `vector`.
2. Intialize it with 0's.
3. Then for each letter in First word increment in the corresponding position. `a[first[i]-'A']++;`
4. For the second word do the same but this time decrease by 1. `a[second[i]-'A']--;`
5. At last check if any of the array position is `<0`. If yes then 'No you cant make the second word' else `you can`.

In case it is more than 26 characters you can use a map.
`map<char,int> m` and repeat the same thing. That will help.

The algorithm you used is complicated. Just think first how you would do manually. That helps at times.

#### C++11 solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word1, word2; // inputted words
    cin >> word1 >> word2;
    vector<int> a(26,0);
    for(auto x:word1)a[x-'A']++;
    for(auto x:word2)a[x-'A']--;
    for(auto x:a)if(x<0){cout<<"NO\n"; return 0;}
    cout<<"YES\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it wise to check for word2 in word1 if word2 is larger than word1?

Comment: @Raindrop7.: Ah I avoided it because the algorithm covers it. But yes you can add another line of logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if it is possible to construct the second word from first word's letters regardless of number of occurrences of the letters, then the following code does exactly that using the **C++** `set`.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string word1, word2;
    set<char> set1;
    set<char> set2;
    string output;

    while(cin>> word1 >> word2)
    {
        set1 = set<char>(word1.begin(), word1.end());
        set2 = set<char>(word2.begin(), word2.end());

        output.clear();
        set_intersection(set1.begin(), set1.end(), set2.begin(), set2.end(), back_inserter(output));

        set<char>(output.begin(), output.end()) == set2 ? cout << "Yes\n" : cout << "No\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can input two strings and convert them to uppercase or lower case then use two for loop checking whether all the characters of the second one in the first one.

Whenever a character found increment a variable `nFound` and break immediately the embedded loop going to check for the next character.

Finally if `nFound` is as big as the size of input2 return true otherwise false.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


bool Str2FromStr1(std::string, std::string);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){

    std::string strName1, strName2;

    std::cout << "Name1: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, strName1);

    std::cin.ignore(1, '\n');
    std::cout << "Name2: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, strName2);

    if(strName2 > strName1){
        std::cout << "strName2 bust be longer than or equal to strName1!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << Str2FromStr1(strName1, strName2) << std::endl;

    std::cout <<  std::endl;
    return 0;
}

bool Str2FromStr1(std::string str1, std::string str2){

    const int size1 = str1.length();
    const int size2 = str2.length();

    for(int i(0); i < size1; i++)
        str1[i] = toupper(str1[i]);
    for(int i(0); i < size2; i++)
        str2[i] = toupper(str2[i]);

    int nFound = 0;
    for(int i(0); i < size2; i++){
        for(int j (0); j < size1; j++){
            if(str2[i] == str1[j]){
                nFound++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return ((nFound == size2) ? true : false);
}
```